# Does Intel Performance Primitives only work on Intel processor-powered devices?

Tags: opencv, intel

We have openCV code that uses IPP.  We wonder if this can work on iOS devices or IPP only supports Intel processor machines?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPP only works on desktop processors. (Intel and AMD, x86/64 architectures. However, they are reported to be slower on AMDs).

OpenCV is poorly optimized on mobile devices, which use ARM processors, and for now, the best option seems to be the Accelerate framework offered by iOS 4.0 and higher.

Accelerate is a function library containing some optimized functions for image and signal processing, math, etc. You can replace some of the OpenCV calls with Accelerate functions (on iOS devices only)